# ember.js Ember.Select multiple=true with preselected values

Tags: ember.js

I'm using a Multiselect view:

```
{{view Ember.Select
  multiple="true"
  contentBinding="App.filtersProductController"
  selectionBinding="App.filtersController.products"
  optionLabelPath="content.fullName"
  optionValuePath="content.id"
  isVisibleBinding="App.filtersController.productListBox"}}
```

Is it possible to preselect multiple values in the "select" box and to change the selected values programmatically? Background: I want to save different combinations of three "select" boxes settings as bookmarks. When loading a bookmark, I have to set the "select" boxes values.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. In your controller you have to create a property to keep the selected value or values when working with `Ember.Select`.

In the code below I'm setting the Greetings as the content of the select box, in the controller that lists those Greetings (check `ApplicationRoute`), I also have a property called `selectedItems` which I'm binding to the `Select` and I'm using a couple other properties to filter the values I want to pre-select (1 and 3) in case none of the items are already selected when the view loads.

This will render a multiple select box with the items which the id are either 1 or 3 marked as selected. You can see the source here: http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/Y8P4m/

Handlebars:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    {{view Ember.Select
           multiple="true"
           selectionBinding="controller.selectedItems"
           contentBinding="controller"
           optionLabelPath="content.text"
           optionValuePath="content.id"}}
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Greeting = DS.Model.extend({
    text: DS.attr('string'),
    when: DS.attr('date'),
    selected: false,
    isSelected: function() {
        return this.get('selected');
    }.property('selected')
});

App.ApplicationController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    preselected: function() {
        return this.get('content').filter(function(greeting) {
            return greeting.get('id') == 1 ||
                   greeting.get('id') == 3;
        });  
    }.property('content.@each'),
    selectedItems: function() {
        if(this.get('selected.length') <= 0) {
           return this.get('preselected'); 
        } else {
            return this.get('selected');
        }
    }.property('selected', 'preselected'),
    selected: function() {
        return this.get('content').filter(function(greeting) {
            return greeting.get('isSelected');
        })
    }.property('content.@each')
});

App.Greeting.FIXTURES = [
    {id: 1, text: 'First', when: '3/4/2013 2:44:52 PM'},
    {id: 2, text: 'Second', when: '3/4/2013 2:44:52 PM'},
    {id: 3, text: 'Third', when: '3/4/2013 2:44:52 PM'},
    {id: 4, text: 'Fourth', when: '3/4/2013 3:44:52 PM'}
];

App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.set('model', App.Greeting.find());
    }
});
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!!! So, multiselect works. But now I realized that I have the same problem with simple (not multi) elements. I want to change the selected element programmatically, but it shows always the first element regardless of the given value. Can you give me an example for this case too? Thanks again. I will list my code, when the entire case is working.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle to add a single select with `selectionBinding`. Just note that for both examples, there might be things you'd have to take care of. This is a conceptual example that sort of shows where you'd add the code to do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a complete example with single and multi "select" elements. You can set defaults and change the selected value programmatically or by using the "select" GUI element. The controller code:

```
// class for single selects
App.SingleSelectFilterController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  selection: null,
  active: true,
  update: function(id) {
    this.set("selection", id);
  },
  getSelectedId: function() {
    return this.get("selection");
  }
});


// class for multi selects
App.MultiSelectFilterController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  selection: null,
  active: true,
  update: function(selectionIds) {
    // Workaround: Reinitializing "content". How to do it well?
    var contentCopy = [];
    for(i = 0; i < this.get("content").length; i++) {
      contentCopy.push(this.get("content")[i]);
    }
    this.set("content", contentCopy);
    this.set("selection", selectionIds);
  },
  selected: function() {
    var me = this;
    return this.get('content').filter(function(item) {
      for(i = 0; i < me.get("selection").length; i++) {
        if(me.get("selection")[i] === item.get('id')) { return true; }
      }
      return false;
    });
  }.property('content.@each'),
  getSelectedIds: function() {
    var ids = [];
    for(i = 0; i < this.get("selected").length; i++) {
      ids.push(this.get("selected")[i].get("id"));
    }
    return ids;
  }
});


// create single and multi select controllers
App.metricController = App.SingleSelectFilterController.create();
App.metricController.set("content", App.filterData.get("metrics"));
App.metricController.set("selection", "views");    // set default value for single select element
App.platformController = App.MultiSelectFilterController.create();
App.platformController.set("content", App.filterData.get("platforms"));
App.platformController.set("selection", ["plat-black"]);  // set default value for multi select element
```

And the complete example:
http://jsfiddle.net/7R7tb/2/
Thanks to MilkyWayJoe for his help!
Perhaps somebody knows how to fix the workaround (see the code comment above)?